# AWS SWF Schedule an Activity

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, amazon-swf

Using Java Flow Framework for SWF.

Any way to schedule an activity for a specific time in SWF? 
Let's say, send run the "sendNotification" at 22nd Oct 2017 9:00 AM.

The examples allow to create timer with a delay, but not for the specified time. 
Even though I can calculate the delay, based on the current time stamp and the target time when the event is needed to be fired, but how can I get the current time during workflow execution, since if you try to get the current system time in workflow decider, it creates [non-determinism](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/details.html#details.non) in workflow and it fails.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
    long sysTimeInSeconds = (currentDate.getTime() / 1000);
    System.out.println("System Time : " + sysTimeInSeconds);
    Promise<Void> timer = clock.createTimer((timeStampInSeconds - sysTimeInSeconds));
```

[ The above code is not allowed since we are using current time from system]

The current time of workflow clock, returns the start time of the workflow, which is of no use to me.

So how I can schedule an activity for a particular time ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WorkflowClock. It returns the correct deterministic current time which is the time of the decision being replayed.

[Here is the line of code](https://github.com/aws/aws-swf-flow-library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/AsyncDecider.java#L474) that updates clock to the current decision time.

Comment: Hey Maxim, I found that Activities decorated with Cron Decorators are probably the best way to schedule activity. 
But the problem is that if I use what is given in the samples here  [ https://github.com/aws/aws-swf-flow-library/blob/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/cron/CronWorkflowImpl.java ] .  Then in the workflow decider, if I have many other activities, then the scheduler activity is scheduled more than once, because of the Replay behaviour. Any suggestion on how to ensure that this activity in decider schedules only once ?

Comment: Replay behavior shouldn't lead to scheduling activity more than once. Apparently there is a bug in the Decorator if this happens.